# Why can't I locate or navigate to this directory that my find command grabs?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, filesystems

I ran `sudo find -L / -name .rvmrc` and got:

```
/Library/Application Support/Comodo/Antivirus/Quarantine: Permission denied
```

and also: `/dev/fd/3`

When I try navigating to the directory I can only get to Application Support, and then from that directory when I run `cd Comodo` I get `Comodo: No such file or directory`  But it is there if find is finding it right? or no? <<< I believe this is just the find process?

When I try to navigate to it using the finder I just get to Application Support, and Comodo is not there. I am displaying hidden files too.  I am trying to remove all files of a certain type so I can get a new program to work properly.  This find command suggests one of these files is still out there but I can not get to it.

For /dev/fd/3 why is this being matched? I'm no expert but I just did a quick google search and this is a file descriptor right? Does it even have content? How/Why could it match .rvmrc?  When I try looking at it with cat I just get a bad file descriptor error. (Should I extract this into a separate question?)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your user do not have sufficient privileges to access this `Comodo` directory.

Try `ls -la "/Library/Application Support"/*` . This should show who can access `Comodo`. If it is owned by yourself, then you can do a

```
chmod +rx "/Library/Application Support/Comodo/"
```

, then only view its content.

You might have access `Quarantine` because the `find -L` followed a link.

### Edit

Once you have done this and cannot `chmod` anymore, then try to see who owns the dir:

```
ls -lad "/Library/Application Support/Comodo/Antivirus/"*
```

Comment: I used this and I could get all the way to the Antivirus directory, which ls shows Quarantine is inside, and I tried chmod +rx Quarantine, but I got "permission denied" error.  How can I gain access?  Can you clarify this statement "You might have access Quarantine because the find -L followed a link."?

Comment: I meant the `find` command maybe allowed you to access `.rvmrc` in `Quarantine` via a link.  I edit my post to help you guess who has access to `Quarantine`

Comment: I get "permission denied" when I try the ls -lad command, what does that mean I don't have permission to see who owns it? I'm the only user of computer and I installed Comodo Antivirus so why is that?

Comment: Have you the ability to `sudo` ? We could also see who owns `Quarantine` so: `ls -lad "/Library/Application Support/Comodo/Antivirus/"*`